# Auth0 v2 for iOS: Renew idToken

Tags: ios, swift, auth0

I have a question regarding Auth0 v2 for iOS, how to renew the `idToken`?

I am using `renew(withRefreshToken refreshToken: String, scope: String?)` method with `refreshToken`, but it's only returning new `accessToken`, and I need `idToken`.

Does anyone know how to obtain it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've managed to obtain new idToken using `delegation`, maybe it'll be helpful for someone, so I'm posting it below:

```
Auth0
        .authentication()
        .delegation(withParameters: ["refresh_token": refreshToken])
        .start { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let data):
                guard let idToken = data["id_token"] as? String else {
                    // No id token
                    return
                }

                // Save your idToken
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
    }
```